# Reading a python binary file with a C# BinaryReader

Tags: python, c#, binary, binaryfiles

I need to export some data like integers, floats etc. to a binary file with python. Afterwards, I have to read the file with C# again but it doesnt work for me.

I tried several ways of writing a binary file with python and it works as long as I read it with python as well:

```
a = 3
b = 5

with open('test.tcd', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(bytes(a))
    file.write(bytes(b))
```

or writing it like this:

```
import pickle as p

with open('test.tcd', 'wb') as file:
    p.dump([a, b], file)
```

Currently I am reading the file in C# like this:

```
static void LoadFile(String path)
{
       BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open));
       int a = br.ReadInt32();
       int b = br.ReadInt32();

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b);

       br.Close();
}
```

Unfortunately the output isnt 3 and 5, instead my output is just zero. How do i read or write the binary file properly?

Comment: I would use some file format for this: csv, avro, etc. for which both languages have libraries. If it is not possible in your case then you should clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, you have to write your integers with 4 bytes each. Read more here: [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack)

```py
a = 3
b = 5

with open('test.tcd', 'wb') as file:
     f.write(struct.pack("<i", 3))
     f.write(struct.pack("<i", 5))
```

Your C# code should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly and thanks for adding the struct.pack reference! :d

Answer (score 0):

It's possible python is not writing data in the same format that C# expects. You may need to swap byte endianess or do something else. You could read the raw bytes instead and use `BitConverter` to see if that fixes it.

Another option is to specify the endianess explicitly in python, I think big endian is the default binary reader format for C#.

```py
an_int = 5


a_bytes_big = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'big')

print(a_bytes_big)

Output

b'\x00\x05'


a_bytes_little = an_int.to_bytes(2, 'little')

print(a_bytes_little)

Output

b'\x05\x00'
```